# Clean install Ubuntu 20.04 and restore vhost sites

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

Can I do a clean install and update/upgrade of Ubuntu 20.04 on my 12 year old web server. Then restore the www, apache2, directories, and certificates without harming my site functionality. Or, are there other files that I need to restore?
It is already running 20.04 but it has a lot of clutter on it I'd like to clean up. Without having to search down unnecessary apps and inadvertently removing something necessary.

Or, is there a better way to clean up a server. The problem is there has been unnecessary installations over the years and I don't remember what they are.

Comment: Without knowing what software and/or libraries you've installed over the past decade and unknowingly depend on, it will be hard to answer this question accurately. However, what I do for clients in this situation is fire up a fresh Ubuntu Server installation in a VM and test the restore process. Document what breaks and how to fix it, then do the actual nuke & pave on the production system 